# How to change page open graph image url with php yoast

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I am trying changing open graph meta with php

```
update_post_meta( $postid, 'yoast_wpseo_opengraph-image', $fbimage);
```

But it is not updating.

What is right way to update ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
    update_post_meta( $postid, '_yoast_wpseo_opengraph-image', $fbimage);
```

It works :)